# opencv latent svm

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I want to use a part-based model for object categorization. for this i have chosen latent svm in opencv.

1. Can any one point me to a tutorial or an example on how to use latent svm detector
2. how can I train a new latent svm detector

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I don't understand why you closed this. It is perfectly clear to me. I actually have the exact same question. From the look of your profile, it looks like this is simply not your area of expertise, so please bug off w.r.t. things you know nothing about.

Comment: I would also say that this is a valid question, and I have the same one. I don't know why it was closed, except that it perhaps did not have the correct formatting? Seems rather pedantic.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I agree with Joshua and Schigh, the question is valid. There is a obvious lack of documentation and examples on the latentSVM implementation.

Comment: This is a valid question and clear enough for a person with knowledge in the area of computer vision!!